# Why can't I delete a record from the table using AJAX and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I used SweetAlert with AJAX for displaying the delete modal, but the delete button isn't working. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong with my code? This is what I have done so far. What's wrong with my AJAX and PHP code? Here are the snippets for my PHP and JS codes.

**code.php**

```
else if(isset($_POST['delete_product_btn']))
{
    $product_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['product_id']);

    $product_query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$product_id' ";
    $product_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $product_query);
    $product_data = mysqli_fetch_array($product_query_run);

    $image = $product_data['image'];

    $delete_query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id='$product_id' ";

    $delete_query_run = mysqli_query($con, $delete_query);

    if($delete_query_run)
    {
        if(file_exists("../uploads/".$image))
        {
            unlink("../uploads/".$image);
        }

        // redirect("products.php", "Category deleted");

        echo 200;
    }
    else
    {
        // redirect("products.php", "Something went wrong");    
        echo 500;   
    }
}
```

SweetAlert Delete Modal

**custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.delete_product_btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover!",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
          if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "code.php",
                data: {
                    'product_id':id,
                    'delete_product_btn': true
                },

                success: function(response) {
                    if(response == 200)
                    {
                        swal("Good job!", "Product deleted successfully!", "success");                      
                    }
                    else if(response == 500)
                    {
                        swal("Error!", "Something went wrong!", "error");
                    }
                }

            });
          } 

        });

    });

});
```

**footer.php**

```
<footer class="footer pt-5">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-lg-between">
          <div class="col-lg-6 mb-lg-0 mb-4">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <ul class="nav nav-footer justify-content-center justify-content-lg-end">

             <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link pe-0 text-muted" target="_blank">About Us</a>
              </li>

               <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link pe-0 text-muted" target="_blank">Service</a>
              </li>

               <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link pe-0 text-muted" target="_blank">Contact</a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link pe-0 text-muted" target="_blank">About</a>
              </li>


            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </main>

    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/smooth-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      <?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) { ?>

      alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
      alertify.success('<?= $_SESSION['message'] ?>');

      <?php unset($_SESSION['message']); } ?>


    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does your code really start with "else if"?

Comment: Nope, it's not. It is just the snippet that triggers the delete function.

Comment: You never set `id` in the JavaScript.